# Stopping chrome from picking up SSL certificates from the keychain in Mac

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, browser, certificate

I am trying to access a website that allows SSL logon. I want to log in to the site using different username and credentials. The problem is that chrome always picks up the certificate by default. Is there any way to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation would be to use the 'Incognito tab' instead of the usual tab that will not save your SSL certificate.